# XCode 7 Source Control commit fails

Tags: svn, xcode7

I am attempting to commit my XCode project to an Server based SVN.  I have it configured, open the Source Control window, and click on the 'Commit' button.  It chunks for a bit, then gives me the the error:  The working copy "xxx" failed to commit files.  Couldn't communicate with a helper application.

What is the helper application???

I've seen similar posts for GIT, but they don't seem to be relevant (or at least not enough info for me) to deal with SVN.

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be a bug in Xcode 7 that you may or may not encounter: when creating a new project with a Git repository, Xcode 7 may tall you that it “couldn’t communicate with a helper application”. The same bug may tell you that it “couldn’t commit files”.

This happened to me after upgrading from Xcode 6.x with which I’ve never had this problem.

Turns out the “helper application” is in fact Git: for some reason Xcode 7 is eager to associate you (the committer) with a name and an email address. Xcode even offers to access your Mac contacts upon first launch.

To fix it, all we need to do is launch our trusty Terminal app (the command line tool) and tell Xcode who we are, and those errors will be a thing of the past. The good news is that it only has to happen once. Here’s how to do it:

On the command line, type the following:

```
xcrun git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
```

Comment: This is using a SVN repository, not GIT!

Comment: Doesn't matter what is it svn or git, it's problem in XCode 7. In my case, when I try to commit from XCode I get an error, but from SourceTree/SVN/etc it's okay. This problem catched two way, one I described above, and the other one is set to Automatic in Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile. At least for me it works

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today. And I open the Terminal:

```
cd [project path]   
svn commit -m "your log information"
```

then you will see the Specific causes of the error. Then I deal with the problem according to the error. So it is best practice to add and remove files via Xcode in order to correctly update the `svn status` (rather than Finder).

In case of a commit error, go to the command-line and use `svn status` to get a hint what's wrong and fix it from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

This morning i had same issue, while committing code using Xcode 7.2

> **Xcode couldn't communicate with a helper application**

I just open the same project in Xcode 6.4, and it was successful commit.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today - out of a sudden, after SVN commits have worked fine for a while (Xcode 7.3). It seems that the SVN integration is reduced to a minimum, including meaningful error messages. I think, that an error returned from the svn command-line tool (which is the helper application in this case) is just handled generically.

So in my case it turned out, that I had added some files to my Xcode project via Finder, added them afterwards in Xcode via "Add Files..." and removed one of them via finder again. I noticed this file being annotated with "A!". I called `svn status` from the command-line and saw the file annotated with "M!".

After `svn revert <filename>`and `svn delete <filename>` I could commit the other files using Xcode.

It is best practice to add and remove files via Xcode in order to update the svn status correctly. In case of a commit error, go to the command-line and use `svn status` to get a hint, what's wrong and fix it from the command-line.